Can a table reference another table that has the same relationship in an ERD?
So we have this problem where table 1 has a relationship with table 2, and table 2 has a relationship with table 3. In table 1, there is an attribute that references table 3. So table 1 and 3 should have a relationship but that will create a loop in the ERD and our professor would not accept our output with a loop. So is it possible that table 1 and 3 will not have a relationship despite table 1 referencing table 3?

If I add a relationship between table 1 and 3 it will create a loop which is what I am trying to avoid. Is this solution acceptable? Or are there better ways to illustrate the ERD

IMO, your professor is correct, indeed more generally that scenario suggests a mistake in the model/analysis, and, down the line, materializes as a lack of normalization: but since all that involves conceptual considerations, it is not possible to be much concrete about that unless we also make the case more concrete: table 1, 2 and 3 is simply and literally "meaningless"...

@JulioDiEgidio-inactive yes,  the professor is correct, but only if we assume that the relationships are not independent. And the professor probably knows if these relationships are independent or not ;-)

Such a "loop" is not wrong if the relationships are independent.
Imagine for example a model with projects (table1) that have tasks (table2) that have priorities (table3).  In this case every task would have a priority (in the context of the project). But the project on its own could independently have a priority (in the context of a project portfolio). So in this example, the relationships table1-table3 and table2-table3 are independent. There is no contradiction and it's perfectly legal.
Such a "loop" would however be wrong if it would be a shortcut, i.e. the  two relationships table1-table3 and table2-table3 are not independent.  This can have several reasons:

Misanalysis where table1-table3 would be the correct relationship,  and the table2-table3 is a derived relationship (i.e. denormalised, i.e. redundant and potentially inconsistent).
Misanalysis where table1-table3 would in fact lead to a wrong relationship (abusive generalisation).  This is a frequent case, when stakeholders/users oversimplify complex relationship (example for example when your credit card payment is assigned to a budget category, whereas in reality some payment transactions correspond to several transactions).
Unnecessary denormalisation, where table1-table3 and table1-table2 would be right under the condition they are always updated in a consistent way.  This could be a justified approach if the denormalisation would be done after engineering some performance issue in tables with several millions of entries, but it could also be source of inconsistencies, especially if the denormalisation was only done to simplify the writing of some frequent queries.

If you have only an attribute of table3 in table1, and no implementation of a direct relationship between table3 and table1,  we have most probably a denormalisation, i.e. retreating an attribute that should be automatically derived (join).
Unfortunately the very abstract table1, table2, table3 and the missing cardinalities do not allow to confirm or infirm in which situation your are.
